# c++ assignment not working in if statement

Tags: c++, arrays

hi I am creating a payroll for specified employees using two arrays. one to hold employee details and one for the needed calculations. employees with senior status pay different tax and rent from junior members. I tried to use a conditional in the for loop to assign the different rent and tax values using a conditional but the junior (the latter else if ) overides the if and the condition is not working correctly. 
this is my code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<iomanip>

using namespace std;
int main()
{

    cout<<"\t\t\t\t business application developers association \n";


cout<<" \t\t\t\t\t\t payroll for month ending\n \t\t\t\t\t\t\n\n";


cout<<"employee id\t"<<"name\t"<<"gender\t"<<"department\t"<<"date engaged\t"

<<"status\t"<<"annual gross\t"<<"monthly basic\t"<< "ssnit\t"<<"taxable 

income\t"<<"income tax\t"<< "transport\t rent\t"<<" total deduction\t"<< "take home \n";


    const int names=14;

    const int attributes=6;

string employee[names][attributes]={
    {"AB/1001","KOFI","MALE","SOFTWARE","31-AUG-10","SENIOR" },
    {"AB/1002","AMA","FEMALE","HARDWARE","31-AUG-10","SENIOR" },
    {"AB/1003","AKOS","FEMALE","HARDWARE","31-AUG-10","JUNIOR" },
    {"AB/1004","JAMES","MALE","HARDWARE","31-AUG-10","JUNIOR" },
    {"AB/1005","JONES","MALE","PRODUCTION","31-AUG-10","SENIOR" },
    {"AB/1006","BEAUTY","FEMALE","PRODUCTION","31-AUG-10","JUNIOR" },
    {"AB/1007","KWESI","MALE","HARDWARE","31-JUL-12","JUNIOR" },
    {"AB/1008","AFI","FEMALE","SOFTWARE","31-JUL-12","JUNIOR" },
    {"AB/1009","ROGER","MALE","SOFTWARE","31-JUL-12","SENIOR" },
    {"AB/1010","WISDOM","MALE","HARDWARE","31-JUL-12","JUNIOR" },
    {"AB/1011","HOPE","MALE","PRODUCTION","31-JUL-12","JUNIOR" },
    {"AB/1012","MAGGI","FEMALE","PRODUCTION","31-JUL-12","JUNIOR" },
    {"AB/1013","FRED","MALE","HARDWARE","31-JUL-12","SENIOR" },
    {"AB/1014","PAT","FEMALE","HARDWARE","31-JUL-12","JUNIOR" },



}
;//end of array initialisation for employees


double wages[11];

for(int a=0;a<=13;a++){

    if(employee[a][5]=="SENIOR"){
        wages[0]=120000;//annual salary
        wages[1]=0.15;//income tax rate
        wages[2]=600;//transport allowance
        wages[3]=300; //rent

    }//end of if
    else if(employee[a][5]=="JUNIOR"){
            wages[0]=40000;//annual salary
        wages[1]=0.10;//income tax rate
        wages[2]=300;//transport allowance
        wages[3]=150; //rent

    }//end of else
wages[4]=wages[0]/12;//monthly basic
wages[5]=wages[4]*0.05;//ssnit employee
wages[6]=wages[4]*0.125;//ssnit employer
wages[7]=wages[4]-wages[6];//taxable income
wages[8]=wages[7]*wages[1];//income tax
wages[9]=wages[5]+wages[8];//total deduction
wages[10]=wages[2]+wages[3];//total allowance
wages[11]=wages[4]+wages[10]-wages[9];//take home
 //ready for printing.
}//end of major for loop
 for (int m=0;m<=13;m++){
 for(int n=0;n<=5;n++){
 cout<<employee[m][n]<<"\t";


 }
 for(int b=0;b<=10;b++){
    cout <<wages[b]<<"\t";
}
    cout<<endl;

}//end of printing for loop


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're facing?

Comment: my if conditional is not working. I want to compute a different tax rate and rent allowance for seniors and juniors by using an if condition. but its giving me only that of juniors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have only one array, `wages`, to store the information of all the employees. As a consequence, when you print the `wages`, you are only printing the wage information corresponding to the last employee.

You can solve this problem by using one of the following approaches.

1. Print the wages in the employee loop right after you compute them.
2. Store the wages using a 2-D array and then print them at the end like you are doing now.

**Solution 1**

Compute wages and print in one loop.

```
for(int a=0;a<=13;a++){

  if(employee[a][5]=="SENIOR"){
     wages[0]=120000;//annual salary
     wages[1]=0.15;//income tax rate
     wages[2]=600;//transport allowance
     wages[3]=300; //rent

  }//end of if
  else if(employee[a][5]=="JUNIOR"){
     wages[0]=40000;//annual salary
     wages[1]=0.10;//income tax rate
     wages[2]=300;//transport allowance
     wages[3]=150; //rent

  }//end of else
  wages[4]=wages[0]/12;//monthly basic
  wages[5]=wages[4]*0.05;//ssnit employee
  wages[6]=wages[4]*0.125;//ssnit employer
  wages[7]=wages[4]-wages[6];//taxable income
  wages[8]=wages[7]*wages[1];//income tax
  wages[9]=wages[5]+wages[8];//total deduction
  wages[10]=wages[2]+wages[3];//total allowance
  wages[11]=wages[4]+wages[10]-wages[9];//take home
  //ready for printing.

  for(int n=0;n<=5;n++){
     cout<<employee[a][n]<<"\t";
  }
  for(int b=0;b<=10;b++){
     cout <<wages[b]<<"\t";
  }
  cout<<endl;
}//end of major for loop
```

**Solution 2**

Compute wages in the first loop and print them in the second loop.

```
// Need a 2D array for the wages.
double wages[13][11];

for(int a=0;a<=13;a++){

  if(employee[a][5]=="SENIOR"){
     wages[a][0]=120000;//annual salary
     wages[a][1]=0.15;//income tax rate
     wages[a][2]=600;//transport allowance
     wages[a][3]=300; //rent

  }//end of if
  else if(employee[a][5]=="JUNIOR"){
     wages[a][0]=40000;//annual salary
     wages[a][1]=0.10;//income tax rate
     wages[a][2]=300;//transport allowance
     wages[a][3]=150; //rent

  }//end of else
  wages[a][4]=wages[a][0]/12;//monthly basic
  wages[a][5]=wages[a][4]*0.05;//ssnit employee
  wages[a][6]=wages[a][4]*0.125;//ssnit employer
  wages[a][7]=wages[a][4]-wages[a][6];//taxable income
  wages[a][8]=wages[a][7]*wages[a][1];//income tax
  wages[a][9]=wages[a][5]+wages[a][8];//total deduction
  wages[a][10]=wages[a][2]+wages[a][3];//total allowance
  wages[a][11]=wages[a][4]+wages[a][10]-wages[a][9];//take home
  //ready for printing.
}//end of major for loop

for (int m=0;m<=13;m++){
  for(int n=0;n<=5;n++){
     cout<<employee[m][n]<<"\t";
  }
  for(int b=0;b<=10;b++){
     cout <<wages[m][b]<<"\t";
  }
  cout<<endl;

}//end of printing for loop
```

Comment: can you please elaborate?

Comment: plus thats a terrible way to store data wages[0] = pay, wages[1] = tax,... You should make a struct and store in a vector

Comment: @pglinnaeus, I agree with pm100. Also, `numberOfEmployees` will be  better than `names`.

Answer (score 0):

your data should be represented like this

```
struct Wages
{
   double Salary;
   double TaxRate;
   double TransportAllowance;
  // etc
}
```

then have

```
std::vector<Wages> EmployeeWages();
```

To create the wages for a given person

```
Wages w = new Wages();
 if(employee[a][5]=="SENIOR"){
     w.Salary=120000;//annual salary
     w.Tax=0.15;//income tax rate
     w.TransportAllowance=600;//transport allowance
  }
  // etc
EmployeeWages.push_back(w);
```

and do the same for employee